# Error in Sqlite 3 Python

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my code:

```
import sqlite3
CreateDB = sqlite3.connect('Login.db')
querycurs = CreateDB.cursor()

def createTable():
    querycurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE Database (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user TEXT, passw TEXT)''')
    print "Done"

def NewElement(new_user,new_pass):
    querycurs.execute('''INSERT into Database (user,passw) values (?,?)''',(new_user,new_pass))

def SelectElement(new_user):
    Pass = querycurs.execute('''SELECT passw FROM Database WHERE user = (?) ''',[new_user])
    print Pass

createTable()    
NewElement("Abhishek","Mitra")

SelectElement("Abhishek")
```

The Pass value prints as;

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002A9FE30>
```

I followed the exact script given in my tutorial.

Comment: That's not an error. That's what has been returned

Comment: Should it not return Mitra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
print Pass.fetchone()[0]
```

In addition, I recommend to follow [the naming conventions of PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Name the result `result`, not `Pass`. Don't start function names with capital letters, use `newElement`, not `NewElement`.

**Edit:** See [PEP 249 for the methods of a cursor](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-methods).

Comment: Perhaps something _other_ than `pass`, which is a keyword. no? :-)

Comment: @Tichodroma, I think `Pass` is a shortcut for password

Answer (score 0):

The result of a cursor execute is an iterable value. You either have to iterate over it, or fetch the first row:

```
for row in Pass:
    print row[0]
```

or:

```
print Pass.fetchone()[0]
```